# How do I grep this nmap scan?

Tags: linux, grep, nmap

I'm using nmap to scan for SSH enabled servers. This is what nmap outputs from the scan:

SSH disabled server example:

```
Nmap scan report for 70.0.0.109.rev.sfr.net (109.0.0.70)
Host is up (0.15s latency).
PORT   STATE  SERVICE
22/tcp closed ssh
```

SSH Enabled server example:

```
Nmap scan report for 255.0.0.109.rev.sfr.net (109.0.0.255)
Host is up (0.12s latency).
PORT   STATE    SERVICE
22/tcp filtered ssh
```

I want to use grep to export all of the SSH enabled servers into a file. The file will only contain the IP addresses of the SSH enabled servers.

For example:

```
1.1.1.1
2.2.2.2
3.3.3.3
4.4.4.4
5.5.5.5
```

I couldn't find the grep command that will do this. I just need to export the SSH enabled IP addresses to a file using grep (or any other Linux command for that matter). Thanks, all help is appreciated. (By the way, I'm reading this nmap scan from a file)

Comment: maybe " cat file | grep "your search" > output.txt"?

Comment: @pregmatch Congratulations on your [Useless Use of Cat Award](http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html)

Comment: @bonsaiviking no problem, any time :)

Answer (score 12):

First, you probably want to spend some time with the `nmap` man page, which will show you useful options like the `-oG` option, which produces "greppable output".  For example, when run on my home network, like this:

```
$ nmap -p 22 -oG - 192.168.1.0/24
```

I get output like this:

```
Host: 192.168.1.1 (gw.house)    Status: Up
Host: 192.168.1.1 (gw.house)    Ports: 22/closed/tcp//ssh///
Host: 192.168.1.3 ()    Status: Up
Host: 192.168.1.3 ()    Ports: 22/closed/tcp//ssh///
Host: 192.168.1.20 (fileserver.house)   Status: Up
Host: 192.168.1.20 (fileserver.house)   Ports: 22/open/tcp//ssh///
Host: 192.168.1.29 ()   Status: Up
Host: 192.168.1.29 ()   Ports: 22/closed/tcp//ssh///
Host: 192.168.1.52 (laptop.house)   Status: Up
Host: 192.168.1.52 (laptop.house)   Ports: 22/open/tcp//ssh///
```

If I want a list of ip addresses with port 22 open, I can just run:

```
$ nmap -p 22 -oG - 192.168.1.24 | grep 22/open
```

Which would get me:

```
Host: 192.168.1.20 (arcadia.house)  Ports: 22/open/tcp//ssh///
Host: 192.168.1.52 (lkellogg-pk115wp.house) Ports: 22/open/tcp//ssh///
```

And if I wanted *just* the ip address, I would use `awk`:

```
$ nmap -p 22 -oG - 192.168.1.24 | awk '/22\/open/ {print $2}'
```

Which would get me:

```
192.168.1.20
192.168.1.52
```

...which is I think what you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you. I actually found another solution before reading this, it was pretty much the same thing.

Comment: If you use the '--open' you will only see open ports too